# evaluate photometric alignment of 2 images

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision

is cross correlation between two images is good metric to evaluate photometric alignment(color correction) of two images in RGB space.

Comment: define "good"... I'm sure you got that term "photometric alignment" from some source. what does that source say about how to do it? I am not aware of any standard meaning of photometric alignment. what exactly do you refer to? your question is too broad as is

Comment: Is the correction linear or affine or otherwise ? Are the two images geometrically aligned ?

Comment: i have 2 images taken from different cameras. These images have common overlapping area. since the color and lighting of the image when we take from different cameras will be slightly different, photometric alignment is done. Now i want to measure the overlapping area of the image before and after correction, to check is the color and brightness of both of them are same.